# Swift return different data types from function based on case of enumeration given as argument

Tags: swift, return-type

I am writing TokenManager class which has a JWT token stored in String. It can be decoded from JSON to object of type ClaimsData

```
struct ClaimsData: Codable {
    let user_id: Int
    let username: String
    let exp: Int
    let email: String
    let orig_iat: String
}
```

Now I would love to have one function responsible for giving particular piece of data. But it should only return data if isAuthorised property of TokenManager is true therefor claimsData isn't nil.  So I wrote this piece of code:

```
enum ClaimsOfInt {
    case user_id
    case exp
}

enum ClaimsOfString {
    case username
    case email
    case orig_iat
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case notAuthorised
}

func get(_ claim: ClaimsOfInt) -> Result<Int> {
    if let claimsData = claimsData {
        switch claim {
        case .user_id:
            return .success(claimsData.user_id)
        case .exp:
            return .success(claimsData.exp)
        }
    } else {
        return .notAuthorised
    }
}

func get(_ claim: ClaimsOfString) -> Result<String> {
    if let claimsData = claimsData {
        switch claim {
        case .username:
            return . success(claimsData.username)
        case .email:
            return . success(claimsData.email)
        case .orig_iat:
            return . success(claimsData.orig_iat)
        }
    } else {
        return .notAuthorised
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two functions one for each type. I guess it's good enough for now, but I am wondering is it possible to somehow write this as one functions using for example generics? If so how would it look like? Using Any may be one option but as far as my knowledge goes it isn't very swifty.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `Result<ClaimsData>`?

Comment: @Cristik returning whole struct (and having to create all of its properties) when someone asked for only one of it’s property doesn’t sound like a great idea.

Comment: But all fields are already created, you just discard the other ones. Also your approach would require boilerplate code to be added for every new property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have different return types, depending on the value of a function argument.

But you could write a generic function which takes a *key path* argument:

```
func get<T>(claimsData: ClaimsData?, key: KeyPath<ClaimsData, T>) -> Result<T> {
    if let claimsData = claimsData {
        return .success(claimsData[keyPath: key])
    } else {
        return .notAuthorised
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let result = get(claimsData: claimsData, key: \.user_id)
```

Here the result type is inferred as `Result<Int>`.

Comment: I have never heard of KeyPath. If you have any good quality resource I would be very thankful for posting link.

Comment: @3Qax: Here is the original proposal: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md. There are various tutorials in the internet, but I have no recommendation for a particular one.